# how to call openDialog primefaces in portlet?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a method called modalFacebook, however I can not call an openDialog.

```
public class PopupView(){
   public void modalFacebook(){
     Map<String, List<String>> params = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
     List<String> paramValue = new ArrayList<String>();

        paramValue.add(LiferayWindowState.POP_UP.toString());

        params.put("p_p_state", paramValue);

        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("modalFacebook",options,params);
}}
```

What would be the correct way to call this method?

Comment: What errors do you see on the client or the server when you call `openDialog()`?

Comment: Thanks stiemannkj1, I was able to solve.

Comment: Can you post your solution?